# How to get a subset of object's properties when querying an entire collection in Firebase Firestore? Using JS client sdk v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Firestore `onSnapshot` listener on a collection (getting the entire collection). I would like to get only a subset of the the properties of each object.

Something like we do with the `firebase-admin` using `select()` on a query:

Ex: `admin.firestore().collection('NAME').where(conditions).select('field1', 'field2').get()`

This is the `onSnapshot` code: it works just fine but it's getting the full objects (containing all the properties).

```
const db = getFirestore();
const col = 'COL_NAME';
const q = query(collection(db, col));
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => { // How to get only a subset of fields here ?
  const results = {};
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // Do something with each object
  });
});
```

Of course I can map it on the client, but my goal is to keep data network traffic to a minimum.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Client SDKs this is not possible.

As you have mentioned this is possible with the Admin SDK but **it is also possible with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)**: You can use a [`DocumentMask`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) when fetching documents, which will "restrict a get operation on a document to a subset of its fields. ".

Note however that fetching via the REST API from a web app is much less simple than using the JS SDK. In particular the format of the response is a complex object that is not funny to parse...

---

Another approach would be to dernomalize your data: You create another collection which contains documents that only have the fields you want to display in the front end.

The complexity is that you need to keep the two collections in sync: when you create/modify/delete a doc in the master collection, you need to update the other collection. This can be done from your front-end (e.g. you write to the two collections in a batched write) or with a Cloud Function, triggered in the back-end with an onWrite trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Renaud. I'll keep it as is for now, because it's an admin panel and I can live with the extra network traffic. But it would be very nice to get this feature out of the box. Imo, the REST API is cumbersome to implement and I think it wouldn't allow me to get real time updates, would it? Also, I've done the denormalization approach before, but then it becomes very tricky to do simple updates in a safe way, like you said.

Comment: Glad I could help you. "The REST API is cumbersome to implement" => Yes, as written in my answer, parsing the response is quite cumbersome (doable but not funny at all...). "I think it wouldn't allow me to get real time updates" => You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can make query by firebase js client sdk 9.

```
    import { collection, query, getDocs, where } from "firebase/firestore"

    let result = null
    try {
        const q = query(
            collection(firestoreInstance, 'collection_name'),
            where('uid', '==', uid)
        )

        const snapshotResult = await getDocs(q)
        if (snapshotResult.size > 0) {
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
               console.log("Data: ", doc.data())
            })
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error occurred while fetching document: ", e)
    }

    return result
```